# What is the meaning of "Clothes and all" in this passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It is a part of a fiction book that I was reading:

> I'll return to Max's backyard, I told myself. And I'll jump into the
> pool. Clothes and all. I'll dive down... swim underwater... through
> the portal... swim back to my world.

What is the meaning of "Clothes and all" here? I haven't seen this kind of phrases before. Does that mean I'll jump into the pool without taking off my clothes?

Comment: Back to my *world*, I presume? Can you give the source of this passage?

Comment: @Joachim  https://www.amazon.com/Liar-Nightmare-Room-No/dp/0064409023 It's a book from R L Stine. He wrote many scary books for kids. This one was combined with fiction too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what "clothes and all" means in this context: the narrator will jump into the pool without bothering to take off their clothes.

The combination "and all" means that what is stated before ('clothes', here) might have more implications which can be assumed logically. In this case, for example, we can assume there is more than just the clothes that the narrator won't take off before getting into the water, like a wallet, a watch, glasses, &c.

Other examples:

> He ate the whole fish, bones and all. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_all))

> Barney was in his best clothes – silk tie, diamond pin and all ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/and-all))